# Convert a list inside another list to list<string> in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a list inside a list, I need to convert it to list of string.

Below are the list properties.

```
List<UserOrganization> UserOrganizations { get; set; }

public interface UserOrganization
    {
       IEnumerable<UserRole> Roles { get; set; }
    }

public class UserRole
    {
        public int RoleId { get; set; }     
    }
```

I need to find all RoleId and return them in a list of string.

I tried below code but unable to get a list of string from it.

```
 var securityRoleIds= CallingUser.UserOrganizations.Select(x => x.Roles.Select(y=> y.RoleId).ToList()).ToList();
List<string> l2 = securityRoleIds.ConvertAll<string>(delegate(Int32 i) { return i.ToString(); });
```

Getting this error.

> Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'Converter, string>'
>   because the parameter types do not match the delegate parameter types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` rather than `Select`:

```
List<string> list = CallingUser.UserOrganizations
    .SelectMany(x => x.Roles.Select(y => y.RoleId.ToString()))
    .ToList();
```

`SelectMany` flattens the nested collections.

Also, you can just use `ToString()` on each `int` in the collection, rather than converting them later.